# Event Handlers are not functioning properly

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, dom-events

I am developing a small mini-game for my Javascript learning, but I am running into a problem with event handlers.

[image]

I have a system where a sub-radial opens when you click on upgrade skills, and then select a skill button (strike, defend, cure, debuff).

[image]

The user then has the option of selecting 1 of 3 skills to replace his existing skill and upgrade it to a newer better one. It also has a tier system as well. You start out with basic skills (tier 1), and can upgrade each skill all the way up to tier 3. In the picture above, the skill list is for tier 3 skills. As you can see a tier 2 skill has already been set (Poision Strike) and replaced "Strike".

The problem I'm running into is my code. When you select a skill, example: position 1 (Poision Strike), the skill will upgrade. But, if you click upgrade again on position 2 or 3 when attempting to reach tier 3, I get errors.

```
javascript.js:628 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of null
    at removeSkillButton (javascript.js:628)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (javascript.js:543)
    at HTMLDivElement.e (jquery-3.1.0.min.js:3)
    at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery-3.1.0.min.js:3)
    at HTMLDivElement.q.handle (jquery-3.1.0.min.js:3)
```

I have to double click position 2 or 3 in order for it to replace the skill which is annoying. Most gamers expect when you click the skill 1 time on a upgrade screen, it will do so instantly. I do not want my users to double-click everytime they want to upgrade a skill. Below is the code.

Main Area or Problem

```
$('#upgradeSkillsBar').one('click', '#position1', function(){
    removeSkillButton(object);
    addSkillButton(skillList[0]);
    removeRadialSubMenu(); 
});

$('#upgradeSkillsBar').one('click', '#position2', function(){
    removeSkillButton(object);
    addSkillButton(skillList[1]);
    removeRadialSubMenu(); 
});

$('#upgradeSkillsBar').one('click', '#position3', function(){
    removeSkillButton(object);
    addSkillButton(skillList[2]);
    removeRadialSubMenu(); 
});
```

Entire Function

```
function radialSelector(object){
    var skillList;
    switch (object){
        case strike:
            skillList = [poisonstrike, bluntstrike, quickstrike];
            break;
        case poisonstrike:
            skillList = [venom, immunity, toxic];
            break;
        case bluntstrike:
            skillList = [eviscerate, bruteforce, revenge];
            break;
        case quickstrike:
            skillList = [nimblelance, whirlwind, backstab];
            break;
        case defend:
            skillList = [holdtheline, quickrecovery, repairarmor];
            break;
        case holdtheline:
            skillList = [stronghold, titan, heavyarmor];
            break;
        case quickrecovery:
            skillList = [impenetrable, untouchable, fortifiedarmor];
            break;
        case repairarmor:
            skillList = [stonewall, stout, unbreakablearmor];
            break;
        case cure:
            skillList = [cura, blessing, healingwind];    
            break;
        case debuff:
            skillList = [lowerstrength, lowerarmor, loweragility];
            break;
        default:
            console.log("radialSelector() has set its switch statement to default")
    }
    
    for (var i=0, l=skillList.length; i<l; i++) {
        radialSubMenuSkills("position"+(i+1), skillList[i]);
    }
    

    $('#upgradeSkillsBar').one('click', '#position1', function(){
        removeSkillButton(object);
        addSkillButton(skillList[0]);
        removeRadialSubMenu(); 
    });
    
    $('#upgradeSkillsBar').one('click', '#position2', function(){
        removeSkillButton(object);
        addSkillButton(skillList[1]);
        removeRadialSubMenu(); 
    });
    
    $('#upgradeSkillsBar').one('click', '#position3', function(){
        removeSkillButton(object);
        addSkillButton(skillList[2]);
        removeRadialSubMenu(); 
    });
}
```

Line 628

```
function removeSkillButton(object) {
    var x = dom.el(object.name);
    console.log(object);
    x.parentNode.removeChild(x);
}
```

Console Log on first upgrade click position 1:

```
javascript.js:627 Object {name: "Strike", tier: 1, category: "Attack", description: "Basic Attack", imageURL: undefined}
```

Console Log on second upgrade click position 2 or 3:

```
javascript.js:627 Object {name: "Strike", tier: 1, category: "Attack", description: "Basic Attack", imageURL: undefined}
javascript.js:628 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of null
    at removeSkillButton (javascript.js:628)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (javascript.js:543)
    at HTMLDivElement.e (jquery-3.1.0.min.js:3)
    at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery-3.1.0.min.js:3)
    at HTMLDivElement.q.handle (jquery-3.1.0.min.js:3)
```

Comment: have you tried debugging on the second click event? it appears that the node doesn't have a parent...meaning you should add `console.log(x);`  so you can see the issue.

Comment: What is `dom.el()`?

Comment: The error means that `dom.el('Strike')` is returning `null`.

Comment: @abc123 The error indicates that `x` is `null`, not that it doesn't have a pareent.

Comment: dom.el is short for document.getElementById(id). My assumption is on the first click, I change or update the skill from "strike" to "poison strike", but when I click position 2 or 3 on the 2nd attempt, it still registers "strike", which no longer exists, because its been updated to "poison strike".

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
switch (object){
```

needs to be

```
switch (object.name){
```

because you seem to be using `object` as an actual object, and `object.name` as a string.

Is it possible that because of this, the switch statements are not properly updating the `skillList` array?